# I am having difficulty understanding this part of apple block programming

Tags: ios

this is from [apple block programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW2), can anyone tell me what it means

> Stack (non-static) variables local to the enclosing lexical scope are
>   captured as const variables.

Comment: It means what it says. Which terms are you unfamiliar with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have:

```
int i = 5; // in stack
```

Then in block you have:

```
...
i++; // can't do that, because i now inside the block is a const
...
```

You're going to add __block to `i` declaration to be able to change value of `i` inside a block like this:

```
__block int i = 5; // remove __block and see the error

void (^myBlock)(void) = ^{
    NSLog(@"[inside block] i = %i", i); // no error even without __block
    i++; // error here without __block
};

myBlock();

NSLog(@"[outside block] i = %i", i);
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that if you have a local variable declared in the scope where you define the block, then you can refer that variable in the block but you cannot change its value nor see any changes made from outside to its value.

```
//-- this is the "Stack (non-static) variables local to the enclosing lexical scope"
int x = 123;

void (^printXAndY)(int) = ^(int y) {

   printf("%d %d\n", x, y);             //-- you can use x inside the block
};
```

x behaves as a const variable, i.e., its value is frozen at the moment when the block is defined and you can't modify it.

Contrast this to the use of the `__block` qualifier in order to be able to modify the value of that variable.